# Integrate Google Cast into Android TV App

Tags: android, casting, google-cast, android-tv

Does anybody know if its possible to integrate the [Google Cast SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/) in a native Android TV App to enable second screen functions provided in the SDK? My understanding from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver) is, that it only works with cast applications provided from a server and written in HTML not Java as the native Android TV Apps.
But some of the preinstalled applications on the Android TV seem support these second screen functions when I connect my smartphone, as the Netflix app for example.
Am I missing something or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android TV is a cast ready device. So you can use it the same way you'd write apps for a Chromecast. Yes, the server is HTML + JavaScript, but you access it via the client app (and most of the times your can just use one of the default ones)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! on September 2020 Google release the Android Receiver SDK for Android TV. This is the official site:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv_receiver

This is the Google Codelab
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-connect-atv

Basically you will need the sender app and the receiver app. Usually the sender app is the phone app and the receiver app will be the Android TV app. It can also be the same apk. For example the same app could handle phone layout and be the Sender App and the same app could handle TV layouts and be the receiver app.

In any case you will need to create an Application in:
https://cast.google.com/publish

And Follow the instructions how to add an Android TV dongle via the Chromecast Built-in Serial Number. Everything is well documented.

Take also in mind that you will need to re-think how the sender and the receiver app works and synch the `ExpandedControllerActivity` in your Sender App with your player (if your app is a streaming app).

NOTE: With this approach you DO NOT NEED any web receiver app BUT any Android TV without your app installed won't work with this "receiver". Ideally you will need the Web receiver and this new Android TV receiver it is just a plus to allow your users has a better UX while using your Android TV app.